# Regular expression to validate a name

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that satisfies the following:

- The length of the name should be between 2 and 30 characters (both inclusive)
- The name can contain only alphabets and spaces
- The first character of each word of the name should be an upper case alphabet
- Each word should be separated by a space
- The name should not start or end with a space
- Special characters should not be allowed

Here's what I got so far:

```
^[A-Z][a-zA-z ]{1,29}$
```

If I put a [^ ] at the end, it allows a special character.

Comment: so what does not work now?

Comment: try: `^(?=.{2,30}$)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:\h+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$`

Comment: Unrelated, but this kind of name validation is extremely annoying for many people because it forces them to use, and potentially remember, how they butchered their name to meet the arbitrary validation.

Comment: See also [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^[A-Z](?=.{1,29}$)[A-Za-z]*(?:\h+[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase char A-Z
- `(?=.{1,29}$)` Assert 1-29 chars to the right till the end of the string
- `[A-Za-z]*` Optionally match a char A-Za-z
- `(?:\h+[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*` Optionally repeat 1+ horizontal whitespace chars followed by again an uppercase char A-Z and optional chars A-Za-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ncLts/1)

In Java with the doubled backslashes

```
String regex = "^[A-Z](?=.{1,29}$)[A-Za-z]*(?:\\h+[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*$";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var pattern = Pattern.compile("^((?=.{1,29}$)[A-Z]\\w*(\\s[A-Z]\\w*)*)$");
    var matcher = pattern.matcher("Multiple Words With One Space Separator");
    System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // false
    matcher = pattern.matcher("Multiple Words");
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "[A-Z](?=.{1,29}$)[A-Za-z]{1,}([ ][A-Z][A-Za-z]{1,})*";
```

Comment: `{1,}` is a really clumsy way to write `+`